# Meaning of "broken off short"

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

What does "the handle broken off short" mean when referring to an axe?

Does it mean the handle is broken off and it is a little far from the rest, or that it is broken close to the axe and there is only a small part of the handle still attached, or something else?

(The Wonderful Wizard of Oz - Chapter 13 - Rescuing the Tin Woodman)

Comment: Please, provide more context. We have no way of knowing what this means without more information.

Comment: I edited the question and here is the full phrase: His axe was near him, but the blade was rusted and the handle broken off short.

Comment: +1 Just for asking about this wonderful book. Please put the full phrase in the question itself, not just in comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common idiom, which really means little or nothing more than *broken off* by itself. *Short* is the result of the breaking: the handle is now short, or at least substantially shorter than it was.

In my experience the expression is used more often intransitively, of utterances, than transitively of physical objects:

> “What in the world is—?” He broke off short. “Oh. Now I see.”

Comment: The idiomatic *broke off short* is indeed common in relation to discourse, but it would be vanishingly rare for that sense to be intended with the form ***broken** off short*.

Comment: Not as rare as the verbing of _aposiopesis_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Rare, but not unknown. Google Books gives 4 instances among 107 actual hits on “broken off short”, from Edith Nesbit (2), James Jones and Georgette Heyer, and three more instances in which texts are so broken.